# How to remove all multibyte characters in PHP?

Tags: php, replace, persian, multibyte

I want to filter my variable and remove all multibyte characters except some of them (A list of Persian characters that I have).
How could I do that in PHP?
**Edit #1:**
Here is my string code:

```
// variable
$str = ' سلامoff3 ';

// array of persian characters
$to = ['ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'چ', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ',
        'ر', 'ز', 'ژ', 'س', 'ش', 'ص', 'ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ',
        'ف', 'ق', 'ک', 'گ', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'و', 'ه', 'ی', 'ء',];
```

I want to replace all multibyte characters except persian characters (there are persian characters and **one multibyte hidden character after digit 3**).
**Edit #2:**
The hidden character does not get visible but in phpStorm it's visible. I think StackOverFlow is filtering invalid characters (what I want to do).

Comment: start by showing us the variable and list of Persian chars, and what you've tried so far. (not my down-vote)

Comment: You need to give us some information. what is the list of character you want to keep and what are the one you want to remove. Also, what is your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward way to do this would be using [`mb_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php):

```
$str = ' سلامoff3 '; // variable
$to = ['ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'چ', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'ژ', 'س', 'ش', 'ص', 'ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ک', 'گ', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'و', 'ه', 'ی', 'ء',]; //
$cleaned = "";
for ($i = 0;$i <mb_strlen($str);$i++) {
    $char = mb_substr($str,$i,1);
    if (mb_strlen($char) == strlen($char) || in_array($char,$to)) {
        $cleaned .= $char;
    }
}
print_r($cleaned);
```

Idea is to go through each character (via mb functions to get actual characters) and check if it's either single byte or in the permitted list before adding it to a new string.

Note that this solution requires [`mb_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)